# How to pass value attribute of an object was saved, to view to create new object has that same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a new form for create question and answers. This is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@question_type, @question], url: path, defaults: { error: false } do |question_form| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: question_form.object %>

  <div class="question_fields well">
    <%= question_form.input :content, input_html: { rows: 4, class: 'span6' } %>
    <%= question_form.input :mark, input_html: { class: 'span1' } %>
    <%= question_form.association :topic %>
  </div>
  <%= question_form.simple_fields_for :answers do |answer_form| %>
    <%= render 'answer', f: answer_form %>
  <% end %>
  <%= question_form.button :submit, class: "new_resource" %>
<% end %>
```

The question have 3 fields: content, mark, topic.

This is my `create` action in question controller:

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  @question.question_type_id = params[:question_type_id]
  @question.user_id = current_user.id

  if @question.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfully created question."
    redirect_to new_question_type_question_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
resources :question_types, only: [:index] do
  resources :questions
end
```

Now, i want after user submit to create question successful, it will show new form again, but the `topic` select will display the topic of question was just saved. How can i do that?

Comment: use the params[:question_topic_id] ?

Comment: I just have params[:topic_id], but how can i pass it to new page after redirect_to? or will have other way to do it?

Comment: `redirect_to whatever_action_path, :topic_id => params[:topic_id]` could work. Let me know if it works ;)

Comment: Its supposed to be inside the new_question_type_question_path actually... Like `redirect_to new_question_type_question_path(:topic_id => @question.topic_id )` and then use `<%= question_form.association :topic, params[:topic_id) %>` (assuming the last argument is the selected option)

Comment: thanks, @Santosh has give more info, i will follow him to check if it work, anyway thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1 Solution -**

If I understood your question correctly you can pass question's topic_id to new action after
question saved successfully.

```
redirect_to new_question_type_question_path(:topic_id => @question.topic_id )
```

then in new action of questions controller, add topic_id if params[:topic_id] present?

something like this,

```
def new
  ...
  ...
  @topic_id = params[:topic_id] if params[:topic_id].present?
end
```

then in new form, display your topic using this @topic_id instance variable. I don't know too much about simple_form_for, but you can do something like,

```
<%= question_form.association :topic, :selected => (@topic_id.present? ? @topic_id : '') %>
```

OR

**#2 Solution**

To display the topic of last question saved, you just need last question object in new action.
You don't need to do above steps of #1 Solution

```
def new
  ...
  ...
  @topic_id = current_user.questions.order('created_at ASC').last.topic_id if current_user.questions.present?
end
```

In new form do same thing as given in #1 Solution,

```
<%= question_form.association :topic, :selected => (@topic_id.present? ? @topic_id : '')
```

Comment: Thanks, i will check it. The simple form has not `:selected`, so maybe i will find another way to display it.

Comment: oh, sorry, your code works perfectly. I don't need to change anything. Thanks you so much :D

Comment: it has small problem, when i stop server and start again, and go to create new question page, it still have the last topic, i means it doesn't reset?

Comment: Means you want to display the topic of last question saved?

Comment: you helped me done it, but i means the topic will be the topic of last question was saved forever if i don't change topic again? it seems your code has fixed topic to last topic.

Comment: am i still need this?: `:selected => (@topic_id.present? ? @topic_id : '')`

Comment: the #2 solution not works, it return the topic before last topic of user. The problem with #1 solution is not important, I just think it can do better, if it's not, it's also okay. So I will still use #1 solution. Thanks again :)